# Eucalyptus bfEBS images

Tags: eucalyptus

I am trying to create a Eucalyptus EBS backed image from an Ubuntu cloud image. I have tried all sorts of different methods I have found on Google and nothing works. I have tried creating a new partition, labeling it cloudimg-rootfs and verifying both fstab and menu.lst are looking for that. I have tried just dd from the image to both the disk itself and to a primary partition and several other methods.. Nothing works. Does anyone actually know how to get a bfEBS going on eucalyptus?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the following KB article:

[Creating an Ubuntu EBS-backed EMI from an Existing Instance Store-Backed Instance](https://support.eucalyptus.com/hc/en-us/articles/201605884-Creating-an-Ubuntu-EBS-backed-EMI-from-an-Existing-Instance-Store-Backed-Instance)

This explains how to create an EBS-backed Ubuntu image from an existing Ubuntu instance store-backed instance on Eucalyptus.

Please let us know if you have any questions.

Cheers,

Comment: The one tutorial I didn't try, this worked. The problem was setting the drive to boot,

"sudo parted --script /dev/vdb mklabel msdos mkpart primary 0% 100% set 1 boot on"

which I had not seen before. 

Thanks a lot!